# lxml.html working with unicode data

Tags: beautifulsoup, lxml, python-unicode

I am trying to scrape data from a website, but the data is returned as unicode. I want to convert it back to normal string. Here is my code:

```
from lxml import html
list1=[]
tree = lxml.html.parse('http://www.qe.com.qa/pps/qe/qe%20english%20portal/Pages/Company%20Profile%20Pages/QE%20Company%20Profile?CompanyCode=GWCS')
list1.extend(tree.xpath('//*[@id="marketUpdate_lastTrade"]/text()'))
```

And here is the output I get:

```
>>> list1
[u'\xa0']
```

However, the actual data on the webpage is the following:

```
<td align="right" id="marketUpdate_lastTrade" class="compProfileTextBold">62.90</td>
```

How could I get to the string '62.90'?

Comment: The link you provided does not work

Comment: Yes...I just checked it about an hour back, I guess the server it down or something like that, otherwise it does work. Can you please try again later and let me know how I can solve this?

Comment: I cannot even reach the homepage so there is definitely something wrong

Comment: Yes...it is indeed strange. And it has happened just yesterday or today. I visit the website almost daily and this is the countries stock exchange website..so it is a bit of surprise.

Comment: isitdownrightnow says the server is reachable  but definitely not for me http://www.isitdownrightnow.com/qe.com.qa.html